# How to get this program to work in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips

The following program doesn't stop. How to make it stop?

```
.data
    message: .asciiz "Calling the Procedure."
    exitMessage: .asciiz "\nExiting properly"
.text
    main:
        jal DisplayMessage
        jal exit
        #End of the program.        

    #DisplayMessage - procedure
    DisplayMessage:
        jal DisplayActualMessage    
        jr $ra # return to the caller

    #DisplayActualMessage - procedure
    DisplayActualMessage:
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, message
        syscall     
        jr $ra # return to the caller


    #Exit function
    exit:
        li $v0, 4           #Print code
        la $a0, exitMessage     #Load the message to be printed
        syscall             #Print command ends
        li $v0, 10          #Exit code
        syscall
```

Is it possible to create a common function to print different text messages?

Answer (score 2):

The `jal` instruction modifies the `$ra` register, so what happens is this:

- `jal DisplayMessage` sets `$ra` to point to the instruction after it.
- `DisplayMessage` calls `DisplayActualMessage` with `jal DisplayActualMessage`, so now `$ra` will be set to point to `jr $ra` in `DisplayMessage`.
- `DisplayActualMessage` returns, and execution resumes at `jr $ra` in `DisplayMessage`.
- ...but `$ra` still points to the same location, so you end up with an infinite loop.

When you've got nested function calls in MIPS assembly to have to save and restore the `$ra` register somehow. You can use the stack for that purpose. So `DisplayMessage` would then become:

```
DisplayMessage:
    addiu $sp, $sp, -4   # allocate space on the stack
    sw $ra, ($sp)        # save $ra on the stack
    jal DisplayActualMessage
    lw $ra, ($sp)        # restore the old value of $ra
    addiu $sp, $sp, 4    # restore the stack pointer
    jr $ra # return to the caller
```

`DisplayActualMessage` doesn't *have* to be changed in the same way, since it doesn't call any other functions.

Comment: What is the maximum capacity of stack pointer?  I mean, how many nested calls can be made at its maximum?

Comment: Depends on the target hardware / OS, and how your program was compiled. I'd expect at least a few kB of stack space, so divide that by 4 to get the maximum call depth. It's unlikely to be a problem.